# Add or delete rows in table in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I wish to add row or rows into "bin type" in example below:

[image]

It depends on me how many rows it is going to be. If i will decide on three rows i wish to finalize on confirmation button and continue another table-row.  I wish to do that in Thymeleaf because i don't know JavaScript. My whole project is in Spring/Hibernate/thymeleaf, contains about 40 bins in my sql DB.

Here is my html file:

```
<div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{binsFeatures}">
                        <option value="0">Select BIN type</option>
                        <option th:each="binFeature : ${binsFeatures}" th:value="${binFeature.id}"
                                th:text="${binFeature.name}"></option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-dumpster"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{quantity}"
                           class="form-control input-lg"
                           placeholder="amount"
                           required="true">
                    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('quantity')}"
                          th:errors="*{quantity}"
                          class="text-danger">
                    Quantity Error
                </span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{type}">
                        <option value="0">Select Type of Inbound</option>
                        <option th:each="inbound : ${inbounds}" th:value="${inbound.id}"
                                th:text="${inbound.type}"></option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                     <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-viruses"></i></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf doesn't run (or even exist) in the rendered web page. It runs only on the server, where all the Thymeleaf directives in your template are converted to HTML. So, unless you make another round-trip from the web page to the server, Thymeleaf is not going to help you here.

Comment: Yep, you've got to make a trip to the server.  Here's a sample application where it's done: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields